# Unable to read picked file android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using intent to let user select a video file for processing using the code below

```
  Intent mediaIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
  mediaIntent.setType("video/*"); //set mime type as per requirement
  mediaIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
  startActivityForResult(mediaIntent,4);
```

And I get the result from the intent as

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
public void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (requestCode == 4 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String filePath = "";
            Uri _uri = data.getData();
            filePath=getRealPathFromURI(_uri);
            File org = new File(filePath);
            File news=new File(saveFile());
            copy (org,news);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("RESULT","ERROR",ex);
    }
}
```

I am unable to read/copy the user selected file in the above code. What could be the issue? Also I checked the path returned by Intent from other file manager application and couldn't find the file in path.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20150801_132511898.mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
            at ie.sparta.pinacleseye.Camera.CameraCaptureActivity.copy(CameraCaptureActivity.java:329)
            at

Comment: do you have correct permissions to access to SDCard?

Comment: ya both  android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" &
    android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Comment: i tried browsing for the file via ESFileExplorer app and couldnt find it.

Comment: try to access one by one: Environment.getExternalStorageState() , Environment.getExternalStorageState() +"/DCIM",Environment.getExternalStorageState() +"/DCIM/Camera/". Do folders exist?

Comment: You can check folder/file exists using such command: (new File(path).exists())  . It returns true or false.

Comment: why would an intent return file that does not exist?

Comment: may be prefix path is incorrect. Or permissions. I don't know.  I mean this '/storage/emulated/0/' .